# Handling model change with ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am having some issues handling changes that a user makes to an editable field in ag-grid. While everything works fine I notice that the change event is fired everytime I press any key ( while editing the input text field). I have created a demo of the issue that I am facing

https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/2QALNAREVg9E5spt

When you start editing a field, any change made triggers the `HandleChange()` event. I want to trigger `HandleChange()` only after the user presses ENTER. Any pointers in this regard ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `(keyup.enter)` event to trigger your function when the user presses ENTER.

```
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="HandleChange()"/>
```

Comment: better use (blur). -you can "escape" from the input using the mouse-

Comment: I did try keyup.enter, keypress.enter as well but they dont seem to be capturing the ENTER key event - https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/2QALNAREVg9E5spt. From what I see the ENTER key event is somehow not handled by the event handler specified and I think it is being caught somewhere in the ag-grid event handlers ?